# How does a 'basic' panel regression model with fixed effects looks like?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have modeled a basic panel data regression model under fixed effects in Stata. Specifications and results are clear. But, now I want to write down the model in lets say general formation. I spent hours searching for an example, but all models are following a different syntax, I guess. So lets suppose, I have the following model in Stata: `xtreg profit i.treat#i.years_since_merger size i.year, fe`

How does this look like in a syntax of a mathematical quotation?

Comment: Since I have helped you before, I have some idea of what you want. It appears you want a mathematical expression to represent the interactions before *and* after a merger?

Comment: Yes, I want a mathematical expression to describe the model in my paper.

Comment: Thomas, since my model changed a bit, I started a new question for this. Actually I deleted this question a few hours ago, but it seems it didn’t worked.